# from 1949 on -- meaning

Tags: time, intransitive-preposition

Example:

> The third wave of immigration came **from 1949 on**, after the Second World War. At that time, Australia’s government made the decision to start a major immigration program, as Australia’s population was relatively small and the country needed more people if Australia was to grow and prosper.

How do you understand that ***on*** on the end of ***from 1949***?

Comment: In this case "on" is probably a short form of "onwards".

Comment: Onwards is a long form of on :)  From now on...

Comment: It would have been simpler to write "....began in 1949..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, starting in 1949 and including the following years...